# Build dataframe with function dependant on its own output

Tags: r, function

I've tried on the web but I haven't found a suitable solution. Any help would be much appreciated!

Example:

```
# I want this OUTPUT df

Previous <- c(2, 4, 8, 16)
Today <- c(4, 8, 16, 32)
df <- data.frame(Previous, Today)
```

INPUT conditions :

`Today` is a function of `Previous`:

```
Today_function <- Previous_start * 2
```

For `Previous` I only have the starting value:

```
Previous_start <- 2
```

The output of `Today_function` feeds the next row of `Previous` and is the new input of `Today_function`.

[image]

Comment: The expected output is "df". Thanks.

Comment: is it always multiplied by 2? i.e. `Today/2` would be the answer? or is it multiplied by first day so `Today/Previous[1]`?

Comment: This is an example. It'd be a more complex function, but I guess it's equivalent.

Comment: For the example, `df <- data.frame(time=time, prev=2^time, next=2^(time+1))`.

Comment: Today(1st row) = 2 * 2(starting value); Today(2nd row) = Today(1st row) * 2; and it goes on like this. The function I have to apply is more complex than a multiplication by 2.

Comment: I don't understand why @Imo's solution is not correct.

Comment: Because is dependent on time (after this comment the question was edited). "Today" is dependent on "Previous" and previous is "Today" of the previous row.

Comment: then just multiply by 2: df$Today <- df$previous*2

Comment: I don't have "Previous" data, only the starting value 2. I gets filled up with the output of "Today" in the row above.

Comment: Assuming your not just trying to *2, I think you might need a `for` loop? `for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
     df[i, 't'] <- df[i + 1, 'p'] <- df[i, 1] * 2
     
}`

Comment: Yes, the function is a complex one, not just a multiplication by 2. I try with the loop, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can abuse `Reduce` to iteratively apply a function to its own output:

```
n <- 4           # Desired number of rows in the data.frame
val0 <- 2        # Starting value

f <- function( valPrev, dummy ) { valPrev * 2 }    # Make function "binary"
v <- Reduce( f, rep(NA,n), val0, accumulate=TRUE )
X <- data.frame( Previous=head(v,-1), Today=tail(v,-1) )
```

**Side note**: I know it's common, but I recommend against using `df` as a variable name, because it's a built-in name for the density function of the F distribution.

Comment: Artem, many thanks for your reply it exactly does what I asked for! However, I've realized that what I have to do is actually a bit more complicated. I'll post again with the full task I have to do. Thanks again!

Comment: This is the question expanded: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41840442/fitting-observations-with-modelled-data-dependent-on-its-own-output